# ConfigurationPropertyCollection

Tags: .net, openedge

I'm trying to build an ConfigurationElement with OpenEdge

```
USING System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.
USING System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyCollection.

CLASS System.Configuration.foo ABSTRACT INHERITS ConfigurationElement:
   DEFINE PROTECTED OVERRIDE PROPERTY Properties AS CLASS ConfigurationPropertyCollection NO-UNDO GET.
END CLASS.
```

the error message from compile check:

Attempted to override property or event ''.  Only abstract properties and events can be overridden. (15133)

The compiler found the OVERRIDE modifier on a property or event definition but the matching property or event found in one of the super classes was not marked as abstract.  Only abstract properties and events can be overridden.

what am I doing wrong ?

`public abstract class ConfigurationSection` -> is abstract

`public abstract class ConfigurationElement` -> parent class is abstract

`protected internal virtual ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties { get; }` -> property is protected virtual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, it is simply not possible with OpenEdge.

OpenEdge Help, Define Property Statement:

> **Override**: Specifies that this instance property overrides an **abstract** property inherited from an ABL or .NET abstract class.

The compiler message you listed confirms it.

But you could create a C# ClassLibrary and subclass the ConfigurationElement therein. By referencing your ClassLibrary DLL in the OpenEdge assemblies.xml file you can access your class like any other .Net framework type.

Comment: **protected internal**

    The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which the protected internal element is declared, and it must take place through an instance of the derived class type.

Comment: You are right, i overlooked the protected modifier. Updated my answer.

Comment: I assumed propertys would be no different then methods. In ABL, you can override any ABL method inherited by an ABL class using the OVERRIDE
option of the METHOD statement. You use a similar ABL mechanism to override a .NET method.
However in .NET, you can only override inherited methods that are defined to be overrideable.
Similarly in ABL, you can only override an inherited .NET method that has been defined (in
C#) as **virtual** or abstract.

Comment: Yeah, there are really some limitations when using .Net via CLR Bridge. Would be nice if you could accept the answer :-)